# Get the name of the parent directory of an applescript file

Tags: applescript

I'm making a small script that needs to use the name of the parent directory of the script itself (.scpt file) a variable.

For example, the script is located at /Users/spongebob/MyProject/myscript.scpt

I need to set the variable called myprojectdir to MyProject.

I've tried

```
set myprojectdir to parent of POSIX path of me
```

and other variations of this based on search results but I always end up with an error

> Can’t get POSIX path.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppleScript itself has no idea.

You have to ask `System Events`

```
tell application "System Events" to set myprojectdir to name of container of (path to me)
```

or the `Finder`

```
tell application "Finder" to set myprojectdir to name of parent of (path to me)
```